# Rotate Image CSS Animation

Tags: css, css-animations

I can rotate an image horizontally just fine, but I'm having trouble syncing it. In the example I have below, when the animation runs, it starts but I need it to overflow back to the beginning so it looks like its running continuously instead of it restarting in the middle. I'm not sure how to do this.

As a sidenote, I know rotateZ(degrees) can do this at an angle, do I just need to specify it at the 0%  or do I need to start it here, and then change it in the 100%?

```css
.frontworld {
  background-image: url('https://cdn3.volusion.com/bstu5.rxjt6/v/vspfiles/photos/WP11001-2.jpg?1529080068');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: green;
  background-size: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 300px;
  z-index: 100;
  animation: world 5s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
  -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
  -o-animation-play-state: paused;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

.frontworld:hover {
  animation-play-state: running;
}

@keyframes world{
  0% {
    background-position: 0px;
  }

  100% {
    background-position: 30px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="frontworld"></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2z8193db/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A straight-forward solution could be to use your code as it is, and only change the background-position in your keyframes.

```css
@keyframes world {
  0% {
    background-position: -60px;
  }

  100% {
    background-position: 60px;
  }
}
```

I'm using `60px` because that is what you have set your `background-size` to be.

And instead of starting from the middle, I've used a negative offset for the starting position, so that the background starts completely off the left side.

Since the background image is completely off-screen at 0% and 100%, you won't see it moving from one side to the other between repeating itself.

Comment: This does work, however it doesn't work in my case. The Globe needs to be in view to start and then rotate back into view like it's spinning. Currently, the way you have it, it starts off the page and then comes in.

Comment: To clearify; do you want the map on the globe to appear like it's spinning around - or do you want the whole image to flip around like a card?

Comment: It doesn't need to flip like a card, it just needs to rotate around like its spinning.So like when it is going out of view that piece is coming back into view behind it

Comment: I figured it out. I just copied the first part after the end and played with positioning. I'll give you credit for this